# Triggering events in twisted from another thread

Tags: python, twisted

I have an application which, for convenience (I am reusing existing code) has been split into two different threads:

- one thread running the twisted reactor
- another thread running an interactive menu

One of the things I want to perform from the interactive menu is to interact with the reactor. Once the user gives a specific command, I want to trigger a twisted event. Here is a very simplified version of my code:

```
from   twisted.spread                   import pb
from   twisted.internet                 import reactor
import threading

class TaskGatewaySupport():

    def __init__(self):
        self.object = None
        self.factory = pb.PBClientFactory()
        self.connector = None

    def gotObject(self, object):
        print 'gotObject > %s' % object
        self.object = object
        return object

    def gotData(self, data):
        return data

    def gotNoObject(self, reason):
        print 'gotNoObject > no object: %s' % reason

    def connect(self, task_gateway_host = '127.0.0.1', task_gateway_pb_port = 8889):
        print 'Connecting to %s:%s' % (task_gateway_host, task_gateway_pb_port)
        self.connector=reactor.connectTCP(task_gateway_host, task_gateway_pb_port, self.factory)
        d = self.factory.getRootObject()
        d.addCallbacks(self.gotObject, self.gotNoObject)
        return d

def Menu(task_gateway_support):
    while True:
        print '''

        A) Connect

        '''
        choice = raw_input('Option > ')
        if choice == 'A' : task_gateway_support.connect()
        else             : print "ERR: command not yet supported"

def version1():
    task_gateway_support  = TaskGatewaySupport()
    thread = threading.Thread(target = Menu, args = (task_gateway_support,))
    thread.start()
    reactor.run()

def version2():
    task_gateway_support  = TaskGatewaySupport()
    d = task_gateway_support.connect()
    reactor.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    version1()
```

As you can see, I am showing two different versions:

- version1 is the one I want to run, but it does not
- version2 has only one thread, and it is not interactive

Running version2 will give this result:

```
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:8889
gotObject > <twisted.spread.pb.RemoteReference instance at 0x88e734c>
```

Which is what I was expecting.

Running version1 will give this:

```
        A) Connect


Option > A
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:8889


        A) Connect


Option > ^CgotNoObject > no object: [Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectError'>: An error occurred while connecting: [Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>: Connection to the other side was lost in a non-clean fashion: Connection lost.
].
]
```

What I am doing here is selecting option A, and since nothing happens, I press ^C, which shows the error message.

I think the problems appear because I am sharing an object in two different threads, and I am trying to trigger the twisted events from the non-twisted thread. I was hoping that, since the object is shared, the reactor would be aware of anything hapening to the object.

So my main question is: how can I trigger twisted events from another thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid using threads for this.  See [User interaction in twisted process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532387/user-interaction-in-twisted-process) for information about how to accept user input in a single thread.

Apart from that, use [reactor.callFromThread](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorThreads.html) any time you want to call any Twisted API from a non-reactor thread.

Answer (score 0):

I actually ran into this problem myself with Twisted. Thankfully after a lot of googling I was able to come up with this answer, works quite well actually! -

```
def my_function(s):
    do_something_with_s

class GetCommands():
def start(self, callable):
    self.callable = callable
    self.startReceiving()

def startReceiving(self, s = ''):
    self.callable(s)
    if s != 'exit':
        threads.deferToThread(raw_input,' >>> ').addCallback(self.startReceiving)
```

Then in the main -

```
getCmds = GetCommands()
reactor.callWhenRunning(getCmds.start, my_function)

reactor.listenTCP(PORT, factory)
reactor.run()
```

Comment: See Jean-Paul's answer for a less problematic way to get user input.  This strategy has a problem: if `raw_input` is running in a thread, there's no safe way to stop it while the reactor is running; you have to wait for the user to enter a final command.

Comment: You're right, I did run into that problem of needing the user to enter a final command before exiting. Annoying, but only a minor issue. I guess you could just abandon the thread with a timeout on the join method, but that would be a duct-tape fix.

Comment: Jean-Paul's answer uses the stdio that comes with Twisted. This is a work-around using raw_input() and doesn't work on Windows. So if you're only running this on UNIX systems that is a fine way to go.